# Which one of the following statements is correct regarding the elements and subsets of the set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

### Question

> Which one of the following statements is correct regarding the elements
> and subsets of the set  $\left \{1, 2,   \left \{1, 2, 3  \right \}\right \}$

1. $\left \{1, 2,\right \} \epsilon  \left \{1, 2,   \left \{1, 2, 3  \right \}\right \}$
2. $\left \{1, 2\right \}\subseteq   \left \{1, 2,   \left \{1, 2, 3  \right \}\right \}$
3. $\left \{1, 2,3 \right \}\subseteq   \left \{1, 2,   \left \{1, 2, 3  \right \}\right \}$
4. $ 3   \epsilon  \left \{1, 2,   \left \{1, 2, 3  \right \}\right \}$

I think that $2$ should be the answer because $\left \{1, 2  \right \}$ is subset of $\left \{1, 2,   \left \{1, 2, 3  \right \}\right \}$
and $1,2$ are elements of $\left \{1, 2,   \left \{1, 2, 3  \right \}\right \}$

i.e $1,2 \epsilon  \left \{1, 2,   \left \{1, 2, 3  \right \}\right \}$

Am i correct?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using $\subseteq$ and $\in$ very formally then only 2. is correct for the reason you listed. However, $\{1,2,3\}\in\{1,2\{1,2,3\}\}$, but depending on how you have defined $\subseteq$ it may or may not be a subset. This is really a question about the definition of $\subseteq$ and $\in$, which varies from author to author somewhat.

Comment: if $\subseteq $ stands for subset and $\epsilon$ stands for *beongs to* ,then only $2$ is correct.!?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you.   1) is meaningless,and 4) is incorrect,  as far as I can see.   As for 3), $\{1,2,3\}\in\{1,2,\{1,2,3\}\}$ would be the correct statement.